# AWS Authentication and Logging

Tags: api, aws-lambda, oauth, jwt, amazon-iam

I would like to:

1. Use AWS Cognito user pool to authenticate users and make requests to an API Gateway.
2. have some way to grant different permission levels to different user groups.
3. Log the users making requests and pass the user details to backend.

Currently, I am using IAM authoriser on the API Gateway, and sign the incoming requests with AWS Signature 4. I am also using User Pool Groups to give different permissions to different users.

I'm not sure how best to identify users making the request, though. Is it possible to access those details? To log the username (or some user ID) and pass a user ID to the Lambda function backend to inspect further ?

Or would it be better to use a JWT access token and OAuth scopes or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using api gateway with lambda as proxy, then you can access the event object in lambda to obtain the relevant information. Try to get event.requestContext.identity which contains

```
        {
            "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
            "accountId": null,
            "cognitoIdentityId": null,
            "caller": null,
            "sourceIp": "52.255.255.12",
            "principalOrgId": null,
            "accessKey": null,
            "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
            "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
            "userArn": null,
            "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36",
            "user": null
        },
```

in your lambda function.

ref: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/nodejs-apig/event.json